# env_var function in dbt project is not behaving as expected

Tags: yaml, jinja2, dbt

in my `dbt_project.yml`

```
target-path: "{{ env_var('DBT_RUNTIME_DIR', '') }}target" # directory which will store compiled SQL files
log-path: "{{ env_var('DBT_RUNTIME_DIR', '') }}logs" # directory which will store compiled SQL files
```

I used env_var() function to use environment variables. If there is no `DBT_RUNTIME_DIR` set then the path should be just logs (because output from env_var should be empty string).

Unfortunately, it creates directory which is named
`{{ env_var('DBT_RUNTIME_DIR', '') }}logs` which means function is not working as expected.

[image: env_var_directory]

If I change it to non-existing env-var, then it will not render:

```
log-path: "{{ env_var('non-existing-env-var') }}logs" # directory which will store compiled SQL files
```

```
11:17:06  Running with dbt=1.5.1
11:17:07  Encountered an error:
Parsing Error
  Env var required but not provided: 'non-existing-env-var'
```

so it means function is working, but not as supposed to.

If I add antything to `"{{ env_var('DBT_RUNTIME_DIR') }}"` it will  just change the name of directory.

If I change to existing variable

```
export existing_variable=test
echo $existing_variable
>>> test
```

```
log-path: "{{ env_var('existing_variable') }}" # directory which will store compiled SQL files
```

[image: existing_env_var_directory]

Is there a bug in dbt or I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jinja context available to use inside `dbt_project.yml` is very limited. See https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/dbt-project-yml-context. From that page, you should note the following:

> This applies to the models:, seeds:, and snapshots: keys in the dbt_project.yml file.

Within those nodes in your yml, you're also limited to what Jinja methods you can call. Similarly, there is some Jinja available to you in `on-run-start`, `on-run-end` (https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/on-run-end-context) and within your `profiles.yml` configuration as well (https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/profiles-yml-context).

The reason for the behavior you're seeing is because `dbt_project.yml` is used multiple times when running DBT. It's used for the path configurations at first, so when you have something like `target-path: "{{ env_var('DBT_RUNTIME_DIR', '') }}target"`, it will just use the literal string. Then, it will do another pass to actually parse the Jinja in the project config file for the areas where it is allowed. However, it does parse the entire file during this phase which is why your version without the default values is failing.

Comment: That makes sense. I can also see that `The 'log-path' config in 'dbt_project.yml' has been deprecated`, and suggested way is to set up env variables instead:
`DBT_LOG_PATH` & `DBT_TARGET_PATH` .
The precedence order is: CLI flag > env var > dbt_project.yml